# Apply material to mesh object I imported into Blender?

Tags: blender, mesh

I imported a mesh object as .obj file into blender composed of several lines, for example

```
 v 1 2 0
 v 1 1 0
 f 1 2
 v 1 0 0
 v 2 0 0
 f 3 4
```

The .obj file uses thousands of segments which join into triangles.

I do not use blender and am unable to give the mesh object a surface.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you've got an object that consists of line segments without facets extending between them. You should be able to fill these in quite easily.

1. Load the triangulated mesh, and click with the right mouse button to select it. The mesh should end up highlighted in orange like this:

   [image: highlighted mesh]
2. Hit the `TAB` key on your keyboard to enter edit mode, and press the `A` key until it's all highlighted again:

   [image: mesh in edit mode]
3. Now press the `F` key, and hey presto (maybe?). Press the `TAB` key again to exit edit mode if you want to move the thing around.

   [image: facets filled in]

Comment: I should point out that you need to have the mouse cursor over the 3D object view when you press keys on the keyboard, otherwise you'll end up doing something completely different.